# How to set a tag to a row in a custom adapter Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, tags, custom-adapter

I am trying to set a tag to the row (or at least something in the row, preferably the row though). Then when I click on the row, I can get the tag. I thought that this is what I have to do, but the tag is always null, regardless of what I tap on.

My code example shows my attempt at setting a tag to a textview, as I have no idea how to set it to the row.

This is my getView code in my customAdapter class

```
int counter = 0;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.name = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
    holder.picture = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.pictureImageView);

    holder.name.setText(allNames.get(position));
    holder.picture.setImageResource(allPictures.get(position));

    //This does not work ---> holder.name.setTag(counter);

    counter ++;
    return customView;
}
```

This is my onClickListener in a different class

```
listVIew.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tag is " + view.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

        View customView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        holder.picture = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.pictureImageView);

        holder.name.setText(allNames.get(position));
        holder.picture.setImageResource(allPictures.get(position));

        //This does not work ---> holder.name.setTag(counter);

        customView.setTag(Integer.valueOf(counter));

        counter ++;
        return customView;
    }
```

Comment: That works. Looking at this I realized that I tried that before with the exact code, but I accidentally used "convertView" and not "customView". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {

        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);

        // set up the ViewHolder
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        holder.picture = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pictureImageView);

        // store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        // we've just avoided calling findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.name.setText(allNames.get(position));
    holder.picture.setImageResource(allPictures.get(position));
    holder.name.setTag(counter);

    counter++;

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: This method works, but I get an error if I transition off of this page and go back to it(without using an Intent to go back). Since Krish's answer works, there is no need to fix the error I was getting. Thank you for your help though.